# std::emplace_back invoking constructor of other objects in vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I am really confused about `std::vector::emplace_back`. I run the following code:

```
struct Thing {
    explicit Thing(std::string name) : name_{std::move(name)} {
        std::cout << "Constructed a thing called " << name_ << std::endl;
    }

    ~Thing() {
        std::cout << "Deconstructed a thing called " << name_ << std::endl;
    };
    std::string name_;
};


int main() {
    std::vector<Thing> things{Thing("A")};
    std::cout << "Size: " << things.size() << std::endl;
    things.emplace_back("B");
    std::cout << "Size: " << things.size() << std::endl;
}
```

and get this output:

```
Constructed a thing called A
Deconstructed a thing called A
Size: 1
Constructed a thing called B
Deconstructed a thing called A
Size: 2
Deconstructed a thing called A
Deconstructed a thing called B
```

Why on earth does `things.emplace_back("B")` invoke the deconstructor of the thing called A?

Comment: Adding the second element is invoking a resize of your vector, a copy of old elements to the new vector, and a destruction of old elements. Your object has a default copy constructor. Create an explicit copy constructor (and a move constructor) with similar cout's and you'll see the new A object being copy or move constructed.

Comment: Note that the C++ terminology is destructor, not deconstructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector` stores the objects continuously in an allocated memory block. When that block's size becomes too small to add new elements into it, it must allocate a new, larger, memory block and copy/move the currently present elements in the vector into that new allocation. After that, the objects in the previous allocation are destroyed, involving the destructor call.

You are not seeing the copies being made, because you didn't define a custom copy constructor. If you did, you would see that a copy of `A` is copy constructed before the original `A` is destructed. If you define a `noexcept` move constructor, you will see that a copy of `A` is move constructed before the original `A` is destructed.

Comment: The world makes sense again. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that when you add `B` to the vector, the vector probably only had capacity for 1 element, so had to move it's existing element into another vector (destructing the one in the original storage)

Let's add some more logging to see what happens:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Thing {
    explicit Thing(std::string name) : name_{std::move(name)} {
        std::cout << "Constructed a thing called " << name_ << " at " << this << std::endl;
    }
    Thing(Thing&& t) noexcept : name_{std::move(t.name_)} {
        std::cout << "Moved a thing called " << name_ << " from " << &t << " to " << this << std::endl;
    }
    Thing(const Thing& t) : name_{t.name_} {
        std::cout << "Copied a thing called " << name_ << " from " << &t << " to " << this << std::endl;
    }

    ~Thing() {
        std::cout << "Deconstructed a thing called " << name_ << " at " << this << std::endl;
    };
    std::string name_;
};


int main() {
    std::vector<Thing> things{Thing("A")};
    std::cout << "Size: " << things.size() << " Capacity: " << things.capacity() << std::endl;
    things.emplace_back("B");
    std::cout << "Size: " << things.size() << " Capacity: " << things.capacity() << std::endl;
}
```

Example output:

```
Constructed a thing called A at 0x1111
Copied a thing called A from 0x1111 to 0x2222
Deconstructed a thing called A at 0x1111
Size: 1 Capacity: 1
Constructed a thing called B at 0x3333
Moved a thing called A from 0x2222 to 0x4444
Deconstructed a thing called A at 0x2222
Size: 2 Capacity: 2
Deconstructed a thing called A at 0x4444
Deconstructed a thing called B at 0x3333
```